# Grid search for vectorizer in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

In Python, we can use GridSearchCv to select the best combination of hyperparameter for an algorithm. Is there something similar to GridSearchCV that can be used to tune and select the best combination of hyperparameter for vectorizer such as count vectorizer or TF-IDF vectorizer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a link to an official [tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html)

```
# Author: Olivier Grisel <olivier.grisel@ensta.org>
#         Peter Prettenhofer <peter.prettenhofer@gmail.com>
#         Mathieu Blondel <mathieu@mblondel.org>
# License: BSD 3 clause
from pprint import pprint
from time import time
import logging

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

print(__doc__)

# Display progress logs on stdout
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')


# #############################################################################
# Load some categories from the training set
categories = [
    'alt.atheism',
    'talk.religion.misc',
]
# Uncomment the following to do the analysis on all the categories
#categories = None

print("Loading 20 newsgroups dataset for categories:")
print(categories)

data = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories)
print("%d documents" % len(data.filenames))
print("%d categories" % len(data.target_names))
print()

# #############################################################################
# Define a pipeline combining a text feature extractor with a simple
# classifier
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier()),
])

# uncommenting more parameters will give better exploring power but will
# increase processing time in a combinatorial way
parameters = {
    'vect__max_df': (0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
    # 'vect__max_features': (None, 5000, 10000, 50000),
    'vect__ngram_range': ((1, 1), (1, 2)),  # unigrams or bigrams
    # 'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
    # 'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2'),
    'clf__max_iter': (20,),
    'clf__alpha': (0.00001, 0.000001),
    'clf__penalty': ('l2', 'elasticnet'),
    # 'clf__max_iter': (10, 50, 80),
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # multiprocessing requires the fork to happen in a __main__ protected
    # block

    # find the best parameters for both the feature extraction and the
    # classifier
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)

    print("Performing grid search...")
    print("pipeline:", [name for name, _ in pipeline.steps])
    print("parameters:")
    pprint(parameters)
    t0 = time()
    grid_search.fit(data.data, data.target)
    print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))
    print()

    print("Best score: %0.3f" % grid_search.best_score_)
    print("Best parameters set:")
    best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()
    for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
        print("\t%s: %r" % (param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))
```